# mysql wrong column increment

Tags: php, mysql, increment

what is wrong with this code?

```
$core->query("UPDATE games SET hits = hits + 1 WHERE id=".intval($id).";");
```

`hits` incerements by 2 and sometimes by 3! I mean for example hits = 3; when I call this function, hits will be 5 and sometimes 6! (add 2 and 3 instead 1).

mysql table type is MyISAM.

query function is:

```
function query($query) {


    $this->error="";
    $this->result=@$this->link->query($query);
    if(!$this->result) {
        $this->error=@$this->link->error;
        return FALSE;
    }

    return $this->result;
}
```

link is:

```
$link = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
```

Comment: In the past when I read those questions the explaination a) was  always that the code has been executed twice, thrice, ... b) in the vast majority because the client requested the resource multiple times and c) more often than not that happend because of a browser plugin (e.g. firebug was known for request doublets under some conditions)

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2762/1 mysql code runs fine as far as I can tell. I'm with VolkerK, make sure it's not being called twice.

Comment: ahh find it! it is from flash!!

Answer (score 1):

The SQL code looks correct, so it must be the context that is causing the problem.

It is possible that you put the code in an element that gets called two or three times per page? If not explicitly, through an include or subroutine structure?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your query is correct but may be this function call for multiple time for same `$id` value. Please check this..

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It was from flash on that page.